# Ability to "prevalidate" email/phone number for community user?

Tags: customer-community, authentication

We are looking at SalesForce Experiences (aka Communities) as a secondary experience for our customers.  We don't have an SSO solution for them, unfortunately, but already "trust" their email and phone number.  I have already created a REST API that will create their `Account`, `Contact`, and `User` objects, but I don't want them to have to use a username and password to login.  We'd like to just use a One Time Passcode.  Is there a way for me to mark their email/mobile phone as verified so that they can authenticate this way?

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce Experience cloud product has below two methods of verification

- [Email Verification](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_login_passwordless_verify.htm&type=5)
- [SMS Verification](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328671&type=1&mode=1)

There is a trailhead module that explains how it works and how to set one up below

[Identity for Mobile-Centric Customers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity-for-mobile-centric-customers)

Comment: I am very aware of the user validating their account.  To *us* they are already *validated* because we already have a relationship with them.  We'd like to avoid requiring the user to validate.